# Is there a way to know which 'when' value was correct in a multiple case choice in Ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

Code:

```
case x
when 0
    puts "You shall not pass!"
    do_stuff
when 1..10
    puts THE_VALUE_THAT TRIGGERED_THIS_BRANCH
    do_other_stuff(THIS_VALUE)
end
```

As you can understand from this piece of code, I want to know if there is a way to retrieve the value of the 'when' that was equal to x. I want to elaborate that the question isn't about how to make this specific code work (for example using *if*), it is purely for knowledge purpose. I have looked in the Ruby doc and haven't found a way to implement this.

Comment: The value of `x` is still the value of  `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying here, but I would think you could do this:

```
case x
when 0
   puts "You shall not pass!"
   do_stuff
when 1..10
   puts x
   do_other_stuff(x)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case x
when 0
    puts "You shall not pass!"
    do_stuff
when 1..10
    puts x
    do_other_stuff(THIS_VALUE)
end
```

x is the value that triggered the branch so, you can simply use the variable x.

Comment: Good answer, probably posted at almost the same time as the accepted answer.